# Increment object's field on creation Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm trying to either get or create an object.

However, if I decide to create a new object, I want to keep count of what number in the list, the object is for a specific profile:

```
cat = Cat.objects.get_or_create(
    profile='Juan'
    defaults={
            counter=Cat.objects.filter(profile='Juan').count() + 1
        }
)
```

Finding all the cats and adding 1 to it seems kinda weird. I was wondering if I could use F() or something related.

Answer (score 0):

[`AutoField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.AutoField) is what you want. Every new entry in the table will get an integer value 1 more than the last

```
class Cat(model.Model):
    counter = models.AutoField()
```

Comment: Yes, but this will increment by 1 every time an objects is created for any profile, not necessarily for the profile, in this case 'Juan'

Comment: Ah fair enough. How are "Cat' objects created and what will the number/count be used for?